# How to filter another column for the same table?

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have 9 columns in my table. I already can filter 2nd column. How can I filter another columns and at the same time remain the result from the first filter?

I tried separate function for each columns but then the function will override another function and its not working.

```
<p> Filter by Activities:<select id="myactivity" onchange="myActivity()" class='form-control' style="width: 30%">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
<option>e</option>
<option>f</option>
<option>g</option>
<option>h</option>
<option>i</option>
<option>j</option>
</select> </p>

function myActivity() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myactivity");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("example");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            /* search column index 1 */
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
             if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found a reference to this problem just in case anyone has the same problem with me.

https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/187399/Filter-data-in-HTML-Table-with-multiple-DropDownList-in-jQuery/

Comment: you may use same function with an argument denoting the column number and for every filter action the result should be derived from last filter's result.

Comment: is it under the same loop?

Comment: yes - under the same loop - above where you have defined `td` using subscript `[1]` - you may parametrise it - resulting in filtering function for each column using an index such 0,1,2, etc.